# <namespace member declaration>, CsTokenType.[ or CsTokenType.using expected, got 'void'

Tags: c#, intellij-idea

I wanted to make a script which gets 2 numbers, adds them and outputs them to the console. And then this showed up: `<namespace member declaration>, CsTokenType.[ or CsTokenType.using expected, got 'void'`.

This is my code:

```
using System;

void add() {
    int a = 4;
    int b = 4;
    Console.WriteLine(value: a+b);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you don't have a namespace or class. You're just trying to declare a method in the middle of nowhere.

Comment: @Llama What? I declared it at the start of the file! Also, do I have to put it like this? ` 
`class classone() { void add() {
    int a = 4;
    int b = 4;
    Console.WriteLine(value: a+b);
}; }`

Comment: A file is not a class. A file can contain multiple namespaces and multiple classes. Methods belong to classes. Classes typically belong to namespaces.

Comment: @Llama uhh... so do I need to put the method "add" into a class?

Comment: Yes. See the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12259540/3181933) on the linked question.

Comment: so you cant close c++ questions @Llama

Comment: also I put it into a class, ran the compiler, gave me 3 errors

Comment: You'll have to look those errors up. I expect one is that you don't have a `Main` method. Something like [this](https://rextester.com/EZMC23353) works.

Comment: @Llama i saw this question now and i am thinking of java

Comment: @Llama nevermind ive done it in java http://tpcg.io/GWK16B